# PHP regular expression for multiple tables

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need  help with building regular expression for text separating.
Now I have some text like

```
text text text
text text text
<div> text text text </div>
<table class="table1">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
text text text
text text text
text text text
<table class="table2">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
text text text
text text text
text text text
```

I need to create a regular expression that would separate the text and tables.
Now I have regular expression

```
preg_match_all( "/(.*)(<table(?s).*?\/table>)(.*)/si", $value[ 'TEXT' ], $matches );
```

And this expression works fine for the text like

```
text text text
text text text
<div> text text text </div>
<table class="table1">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It separate to the

```
text text text
text text text
<div> text text text </div>
```

and

```
    <table class="table1">
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

But for the text

```
text text text
text text text
<div> text text text </div>
<table class="table1">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
text text text
text text text
text text text
<table class="table2">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
text text text
text text text
text text text
```

my regular expression doesnot work. It's return array with

```
[0] =>"text text text
    text text text
    <div> text text text </div>
    <table class="table1">
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    text text text
    text text text
    text text text",
[1]=>"<table class="table2">
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>",
[2]=>"text text text
    text text text
    text text text"
```

How to build right regular expression?

Comment: The [obligatory admonition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be somewhere around this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML('html string');

$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach($tables as $table){
    $parent = $table->parentNode;
    $parent->removeChild($table);
}

$doc->normalizeDocument();

$text = array();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$textnodes = $xpath->evaluate('//text()');
foreach($textnodes as $textnode){
    $text[] = $textnode->wholeText;
}
print_r($text)
```

This code loads your html, find and removes tables, finds all the textnodes and fill an array with their content. You should read more about [PHP DOM](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to fine tune it to your needs.

Comment: OK. It's remove tables. But I need text pieces in the original sequence for wrapping each piece in div. I.e. `<div>piece1</div><table>***</table><div>piece2</div><table>***</table><div>piece3</div>`

Comment: Updated the code, if it still doesn't work you should google for `xpath` and `php dom` tutorials. They should help you out. After that doesn't work, ask a question about you're new code.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `(.*)` at the beginning and end of your regex.  The only time you have to "pad" a regex like that is when you're using something like Java's `matches()` method that automatically anchors the match at both ends.

What's happening here is that the first `(.*)` initially gobbles up the whole document, then backs off just far enough to let the next part (`<table` etc.) match one table element.  Then the second `(.*)` consumes whatever is left.  That explains why `preg_match_all()` only captures one table element, and why it's always the last one.

You can get rid of the `(?s)` as well.  It's not really hurting anything, but all it does is turn on `single-line` mode, and you've already done that with the `s` modifier at the end.  You probably meant to match a whitespace character (which would be `\s`), but that would prevent it from matching `<table>` (i.e. a table tag with no attributes).  You should use `\b` (a word boundary) instead:

```
preg_match_all( '~<table\b.*?/table>~si', $value[ 'TEXT' ], $matches );
```

But be aware that this approach will only work on extremely simple HTML.  There are many, many things that can defeat it even in perfectly valid HTML (nested table tags being the most obvious example).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is this code:

```
$test = preg_replace( "/<table(?s).*?\/table>/si", '<BREAKHERE>', $value[ 'TEXT' ] );

            $texts = explode( '<BREAKHERE>', $test );

            foreach ( $texts as $keyTEXT => $valueTEXT )
            {
                $TmpVal = str_replace( "\r", "", $valueTEXT );
                $TmpVal = str_replace( "\n", "", $TmpVal );
                $TmpVal = str_replace( "\r\n", "", $TmpVal );
                if ( trim( $TmpVal ) != '' )
                {
                    preg_match_all( "/\w/", $TmpVal, $mtchs );

                    if ( count( $mtchs[ 0 ] ) > 0 )
                    {
                        $value[ 'TEXT' ] = str_replace( $valueTEXT, ' <div class="panel-container">' . $valueTEXT . '</div>', $value[ 'TEXT' ] );
                    }
                }
            }
```